# Why is Thymeleaf converting my date from the yyyy-MM-dd to dd/MM/yyyy format?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am building a simple MVC CRUD application using `Spring Boot` and `Thymeleaf`. With my update function I am trying to pre-fill a form and one of the inputs is a date. I am storing the date in the object as a `LocalDate`. If I print the date before I send it to the form, it prints in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format. However I am getting this error in the browser.

`The specified value "22/07/2002" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"`

This is the input.

`<span>Date of Birth*:</span><input type="date" th:field="*{dob}" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Date of Birth">`

I am confused as to why it seems to be getting converted to the `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

I tried changing the field to this `th:field="*{#temporals.format(dob, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"`. I've added the dependency to my `pom.xml` file but getting the error:

`Bean property #temporals is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

I can't find if I need to import it anywhere? Sorry if this is a basic question, I am very new to `Spring` and `Thymeleaf` and couldn't find the answer.

Is there a simpler way to do it without the formatter? I'm not sure why it somehow ends up with the `dd/MM/yyyy` in the first place.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean it renders wrong *before* the form gets posted - or after?

Comment: @g00se it prints correctly to the terminal before I send it to the form, and then the form never renders the date because its not in the correct format

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.baeldung.com/dates-in-thymeleaf) might help

Comment: Thanks, I added this annotation @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") to the date field in the entity and it works now

Comment: Are you by any chance using Bootstrap and the Bootstrap date picker?

Comment: @g00se Yes I'm using the Bootstrap date picker

Comment: Good! I was going to ask you if you'd let me know what your headers are. I've had a hell of a lot of trouble getting the right combo of js and css, even having had to settle on things with, weirdly, cdn-derived files with twitter in their name ;)